# How can I tell within a Shiny app if the navbar is collapsed?

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I have a Shiny app that uses a `navbarPage()` structure with a fixed position, collapsible navbar. I want to be able to check within my server-side code whether the navbar is currently collapsed or not. I am using Bootstrap 4.

Here is some example code that illustrates the app set up, with some pseudo-code on the server side:

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "An app",
  # Specifying Bootstrap 4, as solutions may differ
  # by Bootstrap version
  theme = bs_theme(version = "4"),
  tabPanel(title = "A tab",
           position = "fixed-top",
           collapsible = TRUE,
           "Some content")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # PSEUDO-CODE:
  # if (navbar_is_collapsed) {
  #   do something
  # }
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

How can I check within `server` whether the navbar is collapsed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, arguments `position` and `collapsible` are part of `navbarPage` and **not** `tabPanel`.

If you read the documentation of `?navbarPage` it gives a first hint, when the menu is collapsed:

> ```
> collapsible: ‘TRUE’ to automatically collapse the navigation elements
>           into a menu when the width of the browser is less than 940
>           pixels (useful for viewing on smaller touchscreen device)
> ```

Looking further into `bootstrap.css` we see that `@media` rules are defined, to define breakpoints, when the HTML should render differently. This gives us the hook which we are looking for:

1. Use Javascript to get the *actual* breakpoints (it turns out that despite the documentation the menu gets collapsed at widths of below `576px` on my system).
2. Inform shiny whenever the screen gets resized via the `resize` event. For convenience, we report which breakpoint we are currently falling below). The critical breakpoint is the smallest (i.e. breakpoint at position `0`).
3. We can then listen to this newly created `input` and react accordingly.

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
js <- HTML("
(function() {
   function getAllMediaBreakpoints() {
      var bt_css = $.grep(document.styleSheets, (css) => /bootstrap/.test(css.href))[0];
      var media_rules = $.grep(bt_css.cssRules, (rule) => rule instanceof CSSMediaRule & 
                                                          /min-width/.test(rule.conditionText));
      var widths = $.map(media_rules, (rule) => parseInt(rule.conditionText.replace(/.*:\\s?(\\d+)px.*/, '$1')));
      return $.grep(widths, (width, index) => index == $.inArray(width, widths));
   }
   function getBreakpoint(all_breakpoints) {
      var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
      for (var i = 0; i < all_breakpoints.length; i++) {
         var lim = all_breakpoints[i];
         if (width < lim) {
            return(i)
         }
      }
      return(i);
   }
   const breakpoints = getAllMediaBreakpoints();
   $(document).one('shiny:connected', () => Shiny.setInputValue('breakpoint', getBreakpoint(breakpoints)));
   $(window).on('resize', () => Shiny.setInputValue('breakpoint', getBreakpoint(breakpoints)))
})();")

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "An app",
  theme = bs_theme(version = "4"),
  # position = "fixed-top", # removed to not hide the content below the navbar
  selected = "A tab", # this argument bwlongs to navbarPage and not tabPanel
  collapsible = TRUE, # this argument bwlongs to navbarPage and not tabPanel
  tags$head(tags$script(js)), # include our JavaScript
  tabPanel(title = "A tab",
           h3("Title"),
           verbatimTextOutput("collapsed")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  navbar_is_collapsed <- reactive(input$breakpoint == 0)
  output$collapsed <- renderPrint(paste("Collapsed:", navbar_is_collapsed()))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can test that by running the app and resizing the window, you will see that the mment the menu get collpased, the text box is updated accordingly.